# Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно пишется (с пробелом или без) сокращенная буква "г" возле цифры, например - 2012 г. или 2012г.? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Слитное написание указывает на то, что это одно слово. Но в вашем случае цифры с буквами образуют не слово, а словосочетание (две тысячи двенадцатый год). Пробел нужен. Другое дело, если в ходе набора текста цифры остаются на одной строке, а буква переносится на следующую строчку. Тогда можно использовать так называемый неразрывный пробел (сочетание клавиш Crtl+Alt+пробел).